# don't want media drives to be displayed on desktop

Tags: home-directory

don't want media drives to be displayed on desktop[image]

Ubuntu Bionic Beaver Gnome

Answer (score 2):

Use *(GNOME) Tweaks* and disable the **Mounted Volumes** option in *Desktop* section.

[image]

To install Tweaks run the following command

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```